# Mag 1.9 change color of PRICE

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I am trying to change the PRICE of all displays (catalog, product, shopping cart) from `#66c7f1`, a difficult to read blue, to black. Where do I do this?

I have searched the .css, .scss files, changed the `init.xml` and `variations.xml` where a search brought this snippet up, but no where else. Nothing changed. I'm new to this from a more traditional bg, which was a lot easier to locate :). It's probably simple once I know but right now I'm chasing my own tail. Cheers.

https://www.zapsales.com.au/staging/index.php/be-k10s.html

Inspect element:

```
element {
}
.product-view-detail .product-shop .price {
    font: 600 18px/1.35 Poppins, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.price-box span.regular-price span {
    display: inline;
}
.price-box span.price {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.price {
    color: #66c7f1;
    font: 600 12px/1.35 Poppins, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

[image]

Comment: in which css file did you change that properties, did clean the cache ?

Comment: I only modified init.xml and variations.xml after finding the color #66c7f1. I have tried to locate code with this color. Not found in any .css files. I have found the color code in a root sql file but nowhere else. The theme is Magento Centresquare EM0157 for what it's worth.

Comment: No, create a new css file, then add your css property inside